# Django using a string to filter a model to avoid repetition

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, model

I'm trying to repeat myself as little as possible in my code buy have run into a problem.

My code looks like this

```
from .models import source

def myfunction():
    if  category1 == True:
        types=5
        b=[None]*types
        for i in range(0, types):
            b[i]=source.objects.all().filter(rowdata1='identifier', state=i)

    elif category2 == True:
        types=3
        b=[None]*types
        for i in range(0, types):
            b[i]=source.objects.all().filter(rowdata2='identifier', state=i)
    .
    .
    .
    return result
```

However I would like to do something like this instead:

```
def myfunction():
    if  category1 == True:
        types=5
        param='rowdata1'

    elif category2 == True:
        types=3
        param='rowdata2'

    b=[None]*types
        for i in range(0, types):
            b[i]=source.objects.all().filter(param='identifier', state=i)
    .
    .
    .
    return result
```

Is there a way to use a string or other structure to use as a filter value to access a model in Django? When i try my example 2 i get a Field error, the first one works.

Working suggestion:

```
def myfunction():
    if  category1 == True:
        types=5
        param='rowdata1'

    elif category2 == True:
        types=3
        param='rowdata2'

    b=[None]*types
    for i in range(0, types):
        b[i]=source.objects.all().filter(**{param:'identifier'}, state=i)
    .
    .
    .
    return result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [keyword unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), that can be done like:

```
.filter(state=i, **{param: 'identifier'})
```

or if you prefer:

```
.filter(**{param: 'identifier', 'state': i})
```

Comment: @StephenRauch because now it's using the value of the variable `param` as the name of the keyword argument.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I understand how it solves the problem.  I was hoping you could put that explanation into the answer.  Thanks...

Comment: That was extremely fast and it works, thanks, I'll accept the answer when I can in 7 minutes. Is there anywhere in the documentation where I can find this and more information that you can point me to? 
To answer @ste

Comment: To answer @StephenRauch I think it accepts variables as long as it's a dict with the model name as a key, and the filter-value as a dictionary value corresponding to that key.